# Neo4j connection pool for python application

Tags: python, database, neo4j, pool

Is there a python module can build db connection pool for neo4j? I found that DBUtils and Neo4jDB can do the job. While it seems that py2neo has a larger group of users. But it's not a DB-API 2 compliant database module, which is required for DBUtils. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use a connection pool? What exactly is it that py2neo can't do?

Comment: because it's a web application. I need a connection pool to manage connections to DB from different requests or different users.